# GridView и FullScreen Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gridview

Когда делаю activity full screen, то gridView просто перестает отображаться. Если опустить шторку сверху, то данные загружаются в GridView. Если убрать полный экран, то проблема пропадает Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Адаптер

```
class CategoryBaseAdapter(list: ArrayList<Items>) : BaseAdapter (){
private val list = list
override fun getView(position:Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?):View{
    // Inflate the custom view
    val inflater = parent?.context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_item,null)

    // Get the custom view widgets reference
    val tv = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_name)
    val card = view.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.card_view)

    // Display color name on text view
    tv.text = list[position].name

    Picasso.get().load("http://first-gadget.ru/" + list[position].img).into(view.image)

    // Set a click listener for card view
    card.setOnClickListener{
        // Show selected color in a toast message
        Toast.makeText(parent.context,
                "Clicked : ${list[position].name}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    // Finally, return the view
    return view
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Any? {
    return list[position]
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

// Count the items
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}
```

}

И активити

```
class CategoriesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var title: String
private var adapter: CategoryBaseAdapter? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category)

    adapter = CategoryBaseAdapter(getCategoryItemsFromServer())
    grid_view.adapter = adapter

    // Configure the grid view
    grid_view.numColumns = 2
    grid_view.horizontalSpacing = 30
    grid_view.verticalSpacing = 30
    grid_view.stretchMode = GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH

}

private fun toggleFullScreen() {
    if (window.decorView.systemUiVisibility == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE) {
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    } else {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
    }
}

private fun getCategoryItemsFromServer(): ArrayList<Items> {
    val list = ArrayList<Items>()
    val url = "http://first-gadget.ru/api/shop.php"

    val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("category", "cars")
        .build()

    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).post(requestBody).build()
    var client = OkHttpClient()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val body = response.body()?.string()
            val obj = JSONObject(body)
            val array = obj.getJSONArray("array")
            for (i in 0 until array.length()) {
                var detail: JSONObject =array.getJSONObject(i)
                list.add(Items(detail.getInt("id"), detail.getString("name"), detail.getString("img")))
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            Toast.makeText(this@CategoriesActivity, "Sasat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
    return list
}
```

}